# Flutter - Radio List Tile not filled with color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make an age selection screen. Below is a screenshot.
[image]

As you can see there is no color filled in the radio list tile. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please do let me know.

```
  final ageRange = ["18 - 21", "21 - 26", "26+"];
  var selectedIndex = 0;

          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: ageRange.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return RadioListTile(
                value: index,
                groupValue: registerController.userAgeRange,
                selected: index == selectedIndex,
                onChanged: changeSelectedIndex,
                title: Text(ageRange[index]),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others answer like @masum billah sanjid will work, But I think it will be better to provide data type on `RadioListTile`.

While the value will be string, I prefer

```dart
final ageRange = ["18 - 21", "21 - 26", "26+"];
  String? selectedValue;
  changeSelectedIndex(v) {
    setState(() {
      selectedValue = v;
    });
  }

///....
return RadioListTile<String>(
  value: ageRange[index],
  groupValue: selectedValue,
  selected: selectedValue == ageRange[index],
  onChanged: changeSelectedIndex,
  title: Text(ageRange[index]),
);
```

Comment: Great. This worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `groupValue` property with `selectedIndex`

Here is my example

```
  final ageRange = ["18 - 21", "21 - 26", "26+"];
  var selectedIndex = 0;
  changeSelectedIndex(v) {
    selectedIndex = v;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: ageRange.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return RadioListTile(
            value: index,
            groupValue: selectedIndex,
            selected: index == selectedIndex,
            onChanged: changeSelectedIndex,
            title: Text(ageRange[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: So I tried it but it's still not working. Only the text color is changing like shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: ageRange.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return RadioListTile(
            value: index,
            groupValue: selectedIndex,
            selected: selectedIndex == index,
            onChanged: changeSelectedIndex,
            title: Text(ageRange[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `RadioListTile` inside a `Container`:

```
    return Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: RadioListTile(
            value: index,
            groupValue: registerController.userAgeRange,
            selected: index == selectedIndex,
            onChanged: changeSelectedIndex,
            title: Text(ageRange[index]),
        ),
    );
```